# Rails 5 API - How to respond with HTML on a specific controllers as an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have Rails API app. And 99% of the routes are JSON routes. however, I want to add one single route that will response with HTML. How can I do that?

This is my current setup and when I browse the route I see a string of HTML tags on the screen.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
   include ActionController::MimeResponds      
end

class DocumentPublicController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def show
    html = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Holololo</h1></body></html>"#, :content_type => 'text/html'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render html: html, :content_type => 'text/html'}
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Layouts and Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-html):

> When using html: option, HTML entities will be escaped if the string is not marked as HTML safe by using html_safe method.

So you just need to tell it the string is safe to render as html:

```
# modified this line, though could be done in the actual render call as well
html = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Holololo</h1></body></html>".html_safe

respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render html: html, :content_type => 'text/html'}
end
```

Comment: Now this looks like the exact answer I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most new APIs only need to serve JSON, yet it is common to see `respond_to` in API controllers. Here is an example:

```
def show
  html = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Holololo</h1></body></html>"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :json => html }
  end
end
```

We can drop the `respond_to`, but if you hit the url without .json you’ll see it thinking you’re using HTML in the logs

```
Processing by PeopleController#index as HTML
```

If you want your route to respond as HTML, you can default that in the route to HTML

```
namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :html} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :people
  end
end
```

So you can drop the `respond_to` and let it have its curse, then default your route to take effect as HTML.